# CouchBase Maximum DB Capacity

Tags: database, nosql, scalability, couchbase

How much data can be stored on one node using CouchBase. I want my DB to scale horizontally and each node to have max of 400GB. If CouchBase is in-memory DB, I guess it will be very expensive to implement, because I will need many machines with a lot of memory, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couchbase is not an in memory database. It has a built in cachIng layer and persists all of its data to disk. To answer your question, a Couchbase node can have as much capacity as you have available hard disk space. It is recommended though that you working set fits in memory in order to have the best performance.

Comment: For me key difference between the two is couch's map/reduce oriented view system compared to mongo's slightly more traditional 'query on whatever you want' approach.